# How to set up create-react-app with local packages in src folder while using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package, node-modules, create-react-app

I use TypeScript in my create-react-app project and use local private packages.
The packages are meant to be shared between multiple apps and have their own repositories.
I would like to have my local packages in `src/packages` folder.

Here is my current folder structure:

```
--create-react-app (root)
  --node_modules
  --package.json
  --src
    --App.tsx
    --index.tsx
    --packages
      --my-package (sub-repository)
        --ModuleA.ts
        --node_modules
        --package.json
```

`my-package` is installed as local like this:

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
  "my-package": "file:src/packages/my-package"
}
```

This way I can import modules from `my-package` like this:

```
// src/App.tsx
import ModuleA from 'my-package/ModuleA'
```

However there is a compilation error when `ModuleA` imports a package from its own `node_modules`:

```
// src/packages/my-package/package.json
"dependencies": {
  "moment": "^2.27.0"
}

// src/packages/my-package/ModuleA.ts
import moment from 'moment'
```

Compilation error:

```
> npm run start
Failed to compile.

./src/packages/my-package/node_modules/moment/moment.js
  Line 9:37:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 9:50:  'define' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I think the error is caused by ESLint because it checks `node_modules` of `my-package`.

I do not want to `npm run eject`. I do not want to publish my packages either privately or publicly. I want to be able to change source code of `my-package` and see the changes in realtime when my app is running.

Is there a way to make it work like this please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is working now in 2022 with `create-react-app` v 4. ESLint no longer complains.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this here in 2022 because I wanted to do the exact same thing. I tried it and it is working fine now using  `create-react-app` (`react-scripts@4.0.4`). ESLint doesn't complain about the files in `node_modules` folders nested in `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute imports. It's, in general, a good habit to use absolute imports to solve nested imports hell.

In tsconfig.json file in the root of your project add the following code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

reference:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However using absolute imports does not solve the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

After more googling I found this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4246

Looks like this approach is uncommon and not supported. I solved my problem by moving dependencies from nested `node_modules` to root `package.json`.

Comment: This is working now in 2022 with create-react-app v 4. ESLint no longer complains.